# Gitlab Fargate unable to pull image during CI/CD

Tags: docker, gitlab, pipeline, aws-fargate, cicd

#### My Configuration

*config.toml*

```
concurrent = 100
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "xyz_project_name"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "yieSD7McA-WFMtFv5nzg"
  executor = "custom"
  builds_dir = "/opt/gitlab-runner/builds"
  cache_dir = "/opt/gitlab-runner/cache"
  [runners.custom]
    privileged = true
    config_exec = "/opt/gitlab-runner/fargate"
    config_args = ["--config", "/etc/gitlab-runner/fargate.toml", "custom", "config"]
    prepare_exec = "/opt/gitlab-runner/fargate"
    prepare_args = ["--config", "/etc/gitlab-runner/fargate.toml", "custom", "prepare"]
    run_exec = "/opt/gitlab-runner/fargate"
    run_args = ["--config", "/etc/gitlab-runner/fargate.toml", "custom", "run"]
    cleanup_exec = "/opt/gitlab-runner/fargate"
    cleanup_args = ["--config", "/etc/gitlab-runner/fargate.toml", "custom", "cleanup"]
```

*.gitlab-ci.yaml*

```
image: docker:latest

stages:
  - install_dependencies
  - lint
  - bundle
  - build
  - deploy

install_dependencies:
  stage: install_dependencies
  image: node:14
  script:
    - node -v
    - npm -v
    - ls node_modules
    - npm install --unsafe-perm
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - version.v
      - repo.name

lint:
  image: node:14
  stage: lint
  script:
    - npm run lint

bundle:
  image: node:14
  stage: bundle
  script:
    - npm run build:prod
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/

build:
  stage: build
  image: aws-docker:2.0.0
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ECR_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build -t  $DOCKER_REGISTRY $DOCKER_REGISTRY:latest .
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY:latest
```

#### Issue:

pipeling giving following error

```
$ node -v
bash: line 140: node: command not found
ERRO[2022-04-20T03:49:47Z] Application execution failed
```

This pipeline works fine with a normal GitLab runner But when I moved it to Fargate runner, It's giving this error. I think Fargate runner is not able to pull the image

What I can do, I can install node v-14 in the container image. But what about `aws-docker:2.0.0`

*Thanks for taking the time to be thorough in your request, it really helps!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fargate custom executor ignores the `image:` directive entirely, as mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/#step-7-test-the-configuration):

> The `image` and `service` keywords in your `gitlab-ci.yml` file are ignored. The runner only uses the values specified in the task definition.

As described in the documentation, when setting up your fargate runner, you must [prepare an image](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/#step-1-prepare-a-container-image-for-the-aws-fargate-task) that contains all the software you will need. This must be done in advance. The job uses this image that is defined in your ECS [task definition created in step 6](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/#step-6-create-an-ecs-task-definition) of the setup documentation.

> But what about aws-docker:2.0.0

Another key limitation of Fargate is that it is not possible to use `docker` inside of Fargate because using `docker` inside of a container requires the container to be *privileged*, but privileged containers are forbidden by AWS on Fargate, thus this is not possible.

Also note, even if this limitation didn't exist, you'll also have the same issue with `services:` as with `image:` -- the service is ignored by the executor.

There are some alternative ways to build and push images that don't require a docker daemon (and therefore don't require privileged containers) such as [using kaniko](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_kaniko.html) to build images. You can also see the GitLab blog for guidance on [how to build containers on Fargate with AWS CodeBuild](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/07/31/aws-fargate-codebuild-build-containers-gitlab-runner/)

Comment: Do I get it right, that we can only support one image? I have many steps in my CI using custom images, each specialised in its purpose: terraform, nodejs, dind for building dockers, aws-cli for deployment on ECS. Does that mean I can't use autoscalable solution? If that's the case, Fargate seems to be pretty useless for gitlab runner purposes...